# generate:doctrine:crud not work

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In Symfony 2.8 I generated a simple entity "*DemoBundle:Post*".
If I try to recreate the entity with command:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entity
```

It tell me that

> *'Entity "DemoBundle:Post" already exist.'*

But if I try to generate crud with command:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:crud
```

it tell me that

> *'Entity "Post" does not exist in the "DemoBundle" bundle.'*

So another stupid think in Symfony?

Answer (score 1):

Try to run `php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata` .

Also verify you have not deleted the whole Entity directory (keep it empty if is it).

Clear your cache (`app/console cache:clear`) and re-try to generate the entity.

Comment: I did a downgrade and with 2.4.0 (instead of 2.8.2) command 'php app/console doctrine:generate:crud ' work well.

Comment: I had the same mistake on a symfony3 project, it's why I tell you to clear cache, it was sufficient for me to recreate the empty Entity folder.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that you have typo in name of file entity or name of class.

Usefull will be **checking name of file Post Entity** (by You), **code of Post Entity** pasted here and phrase what you typed to console for option **The Entity shortcut name**.

I exclude error with namespace - error look like *"Unknown Entity namespace alias 'AcmeBlogBundle'".*